# Add & Create ODD behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework ORM and am confused with the below. I am confused that my count in MessageBox both after AddObject and CreateObject is same as before adding??? 
Is this some expected behavior with any ORM? Thanks a bunch in advance.

```
// Sample Code

MessageBox.Show("Count before assignment " + _ctxEntitiesHR.GROUPS.Count());

// Try Add
GROUPS newGroup = new GROUPS();
newGroup.GRP_ID = 187;
newGroup.GRP_NAME = "group with ID 187";

_ctxEntitiesHR.GROUPS.AddObject(newGroup);

// Try Create 
var newGrp = _ctxEntitiesHR.GROUPS.CreateObject();
newGrp.GRP_ID = 189;
newGrp.GRP_NAME = "group with ID 189";
_ctxEntitiesHR.GROUPS.Attach(newGrp);

MessageBox.Show("Count after assignment " + _ctxEntitiesHR.GROUPS.Count());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `context.SaveChanges()` before requesting the count.

I suspect the `Count()` will always run a query on the database, while your newly added item hasn't been saved yet.